# In spring-boot, I want to use jsp, but it doesn't work

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In spring-boot, I want to use jsp, but it doesn't work.

In `application.yml`, I config like this:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
      suffix: .jsp
```

About `Appliction`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(JspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In `Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    private String message = "Hello World";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        User user = new User(1, "张三", "男", 33);
        model.put("createTime", new Date());
        model.put("user", user);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

I also created the directory `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp`.

I visit `http://localhost:8080`  after running the `main()`, but I get nothing.

It can get into the `controller` , but it can't forward `jsp view`. I don't know how to fix it.

It's my [project](https://github.com/gaotingwang/spring-boot-demo/tree/master/web-jsp) in Github

Answer (score 0):

Your `WEB-INF/jsp/` folder need to be move under `src/main/resources` folder otherwise your templates cannot been exposed to the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can implemente interface **EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer**  from web configuration and override **customize** method to change document root.

example : in case webapp folder is under src/main/

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebConfigurer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer 

    @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            container.setDocumentRoot(new File("src/main/webapp/"));

        }
}
```